# Проверка нескольких условий

Tags: python

Есть задача: проверить входит ли кирпич в прямоугольное отверстие.

```
hole_x, hole_y = 8, 9
brick_x, brick_y, brick_z = 6, 11, 3
```

Вот что я хотел сделать:

```
if brick_x <= hole_x and brick_x <= hole_y:
    if brick_y <= hole_x and brick_y <= hole_y:
        if brick_z <= hole_x and brick_z <= hole_y:
            print('ДА')

else:
    print('НЕТ')
```

Но при запуске кода программа завершается без выдачи значения, но без ошибок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: Логика проверки: берём две меньшие стороны кирпича, они должны быть меньше или равны размерам отверстия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема - нету условия после всех `if`.

То есь у вас слишком много `if` и если один из них не проходит по условию, то ничего не выполняется.

В вашем случае легче сделать так:

```
if (brick_x <= hole_x and brick_x <= hole_y) and (brick_y <= hole_x and brick_y <= hole_y) and (brick_z <= hole_x and brick_z <= hole_y):
    print('ДА')

else:
    print('НЕТ')
```

Либо:

```
if brick_x <= hole_x and brick_x <= hole_y:
    if brick_y <= hole_x and brick_y <= hole_y:
        if brick_z <= hole_x and brick_z <= hole_y:
            print('ДА')

        else:
            print('НЕТ')
    else:
        print('НЕТ')
else:
    print('НЕТ')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: К сожалению ни одно из ваших решений нет правильным — обе дадут результат `НЕТ`, а кирпич в отверстие входит. Вы вероятно правильно написали код, но  повторили (неправильную) логику оригинального кода. Во всяком случае, +1 за правильное раскрытие ошибки.

Comment: @MarianD, я сделал ровно то, что просил автор)

Comment: @DGDays, я согласен, ведь я и голосовал за ваш ответ. Первая часть моего комментария назначена главным образом для автора вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Хватит взять 2 наименьшие ребра кирпича и проверить, если меньшее из них меньше чем меньшая страна ответствия и большее из них меньше чем большая страна отверствия:

```
brick = sorted([brick_x, brick_y, brick_z])

if brick[0] <= min(hole_x, hole_y) and brick[1] <= max(hole_x, hole_y):
    print('ДА')
else:
    print('НЕТ')
```